# Every time I close tab in IE, Windows displays 'Internet Explorer has Stopped Working'

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Every time I close tab in IE, Windows displays 'Internet Explorer has Stopped Working' _ Dugh.... How to fix it?

Additional information:

- IE: 8.0
- OS: Windows 2008 x32 in Desktop mode
- It started happening after I moved computer to different domain
- Problem resolution displays: data execution prevention

I turned off DEP for Internet Explorer - it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard troubleshooting:

1. Go into Control Panel, and choose "Internet Options".
2. Switch to the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Reset Internet Explorer Settings button.
4. Click Reset to confirm the operation.
5. Click Close when the resetting process finished.
6. Uncheck `Enable third-party browser extensions`.
7. Click Apply, click OK.

If the situation has improved, try returning third-party browser extensions.